# How do I reset Chrome language, or is it corrupted?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

My Chrome browser started showing gibberish and no matter what I do, I can't fix it. I can't read anything, but I was able to find "Languages" under settings and try to reset Chrome, but nothing is working.

I don't even believe it's a real language as it has exclamation marks, so it seems more likely like some kind of corruption.

I have deleted and re-installed Chrome and am getting the same thing. I have tried to remove the Chrome folder in Application Support (Mac), but it didn't fix it.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/407529/372111

Comment: I had two instances of Roboto. I opened FontBook, found Roboto, and clicked Automatically Fix, quit and reopened Chrome, and it seems to be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a font issue, causing characters to be shifted by one (somehow!).

Uninstall *Roboto* from your system.

Source:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/ki7qss/strange_text_showing_in_chrome_started_after/
- https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/86605680?hl=en